# Databases "Synchronized / In Recovery" after adding server to SQL Avaylability Group

Tags: sql-server, database, database-replication, sql-server-2016, alwayson

I have an SQL AlwaysOn Availabilty Group configured with 2 nodes. The AG works without any problem with this 2 nodes and I can do a failover to/from any of them (this servers are on the same network).

Recently, I added another server to the AG, but this one is an Azure VM. I successfully added it to the AG, with seeding mode 'automatic', and configured as a "Readable secondary". All the databases get created on the Azure VM, but they stay in "Synchronized/In Recovery" mode, I have restarted the server, remove the database and added it again, but always all the databases stays on that mode. On the on-premise secundary replica, all databases are in "Synchronized" mode and I can access to all databases for read only operations.

How can I take those databases out of the "In Recovery" state?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I was using a newer version of SQL (SQL 2017) on the new replica, but the primery was SQL 2016. After installing SQL 2016 on the new replica, all databases in "Syncronized" and available for read-only access.